# "Beautifying" macro

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

Watching Herb Sutter's talk about atomics at C++ and beyond I glimpsed at his idea of an easy to use lock/unlock mechanism that may or may not come in a future standard of the language.

The mechanism looks likes:

```
atomic{
// code here
}
```

Not wanting to wait for a future standard I tried implementing this myself, what I've come up with is this:

```
#define CONCAT_IMPL(A, B) A ## B
#define CONCAT(A, B) CONCAT_IMPL(A, B)

# define atomic(a) { \
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a), std::mutex>::value,"Argument must be of type std::mutex !");\
struct CONCAT(atomic_impl_, __LINE__)\
{\
std::function<void()> func;\
std::mutex* impl;\
CONCAT(atomic_impl_, __LINE__)(std::mutex& b)\
{ \
    impl = &b;\
    impl->lock();\
}\
CONCAT(~atomic_impl_, __LINE__)()\
{ \
    func();\
    impl->unlock(); \
}\
} CONCAT(atomic_impl_var_, __LINE__)(a);\
CONCAT(atomic_impl_var_, __LINE__).func = [&]()
```

and usage:

```
std::mutex mut;
atomic(mut){
    // code here
};}
```

The problem, obviously, is the **};** which I'd like to remove.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: It seems that you did not clean the code enough... what is `func` for? where is it initialized?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: last line of the macro

Comment: I guess `BEGIN_ATOMIC(mut) ... END_ATOMIC()` could be elegant enough. I don't think you're going to find any better solutions, you will always need the `};`: either the programmer writes it, or a macro written by the programmer does.

Comment: @user1233963: Ouch... there are so many things wrong with that macro I would not know where to start from... it is assymetric. To the cost of locking you are adding a dynamic allocation (`std::function` storing the lambda)... maybe a little nicer than `lock_guard` (beauty is in the eye of the beholder), but at what cost?

Comment: I would prefer an artificial scope with a scoped_lock instantiated inside. It is a proven pattern, it is familiar to other developers and doesn't require the use of "macros-as-code".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the trick of defining variables inside an `if` statement.

```
template <typename M>
struct atomic_guard_ {
  explicit atomic_guard_(M& m) : lock(m) {}
  atomic_guard_(M const&) =delete; // Since we unfortunately have to use uniform
  atomic_guard_(M&&) =delete;      // initialization, make it at least a little safe
  operator bool() const { return false; }
  std::lock_guard<M> lock;
};

#define atomic(m) \
  if (atomic_guard_<std::decay<decltype(m)>::type> _{m}) {} else

int main()
{
  std::mutex m;
  atomic(m) {
    std::cout << "a\n";
  }

  atomic(m) // this works too, but I think this is ok
    std::cout << "b\n";
}
```

Comment: This is broken... `if (condition) atomic(m) { cout << "a\n"; } else { cout << "what?!?\n" }`... macros are tricky, try to avoid them as much as possible (obvious approach, have `operator bool` return `false` and change the macro to `if (...) ; else`, but the fact is that this makes for a convoluted solution for a non-problem (see Steve's answer)

Comment: Would have never thought of that! Absolutely beautiful !

Comment: I know people hate macros, but this is a very nice hack to 'inject' an RAII object into a user's block.  Though for this particular use it's probably better to just use `lock_guard` directly since you won't quite be getting the (assumed) future syntax anyway. Of course, David Rodríguez's point about using `if (...) ; else` needs to happen.

Comment: Yes, as a hack it is nice. But I'd get angry if you were to waste my time figuring out what your `atomic` hack does instead of just using scoped_lock or lock_guard etc. But well answered, +1.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I don't hate macros, I just find that it is very easy to make mistakes. The proof is that the original code in the answer failed in some use cases. In general the problem of *injecting a RAII object into a user's block* is solved by creating a RAII object *inside* the user block. There are very few cases where hiding that from the context improves the code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I agree. I don't think it would be a good use here. But I still think it's clever. I can have both opinions.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: If you like this, take a look at the implementation of boost foreach (uses two types of variable injection, with `if` and with `for`). The third way of injecting a variable into a different scope abusing `try/catch`, which can be used to simulate Java's `synchronized` functions: `void foo() syncronized(mutex) { function code }`. In that last case the macro can be expanded into `try { throw RAII(m); } catch (RAII&)`. Yet another abuse I would not like in my source code :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). If you want to involve a macro I suppose you can, it will save you choosing a variable name and it will avoid the (surprisingly easy) typo of accidentally creating a temporary instead of a variable.

Comment: Doesn't the temporary have the same lifetime as a variable would?

Comment: +1, there is no need for complex solutions to a non-problem that is already handled in the standard

Comment: @James: You open a scope, create a named `lock_guard` (not temporary!) and it will release the lock when the scope exits): `{ std::lock_guard l(m); ... }` instead of `atomic(m) {...}` in the question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I wondered if it had the same effect as this: `{std::lock_guard(m); ... }`, but it doesn't, so never mind.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version would use `for` and a `std::unique_lock`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <mutex>

#define atomic(a) \
  for(auto lock=std::unique_lock<std::decay<decltype(a)>::type>(a); lock; lock.unlock())

int main()
{
  std::mutex m;
  atomic(m) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```